# How to use ControlGetText Command in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I used MS Excel sheet for tests but it failed to work. My script is this:

```
F1::
ControlGetText, OutputVar, Edit1, ahk_class XLMAIN
Return
F2::
Send %OutputVar%
Return
```

So when I press hotkey F1, the script should retrieve the text of edit box and when I press hotkey F2 it should send that text, but it is doing nothing on pressing these keys.

As you can see in this snapshot:

[image: screenshot]

(All the control IDs are only for the purpose of testing)

Answer (score 1):

You're using it correctly.

There are lots of controls that won't let you retrieve the text directly.

The problem in this case is that Excel stopped respecting its WinAPI origins and doesn't store the text in the control. Connect to the running Excel application and use its automation interface:

```
F1::address := ComObjActive("Excel.Application").ActiveCell.Address(0,0)
F2::send %address%
```

For SysTreeView32 controls you can try the [low level SendMessage method](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/11115-get-text-of-treeview-control-item/)

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm for your reply. But i want to retrieve any value from any application via using controlgettext command. can you tell me how to use it in the present scenario? you suggested to use com object module. but it works only in excel application. if any other application or software is being used and i want to retrieve any value from that application or software than what would i do as com object will not work there. so please tell me how to use controlgettext comman. thanks a lot

Comment: You're using it correctly. The problem is that Excel stopped respecting its WinAPI origins and doesn't store the text in the control.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm for you good suggestion. One more thing i would like to bring into your notice- as you can see in the following snapshot.  http://i.imgur.com/ZRM21bl.png        this command is not working even here. i do not know what mistake i am making. referring to the snapshot image i am using these codes to retrieve the text of red box area in the image-                                         f1::
ControlGetText, OutputVar, SysTreeView321, Collins COBUILD on CD-ROM - Lexicon
return
f2::
send %OutputVar%
return                                PLEASE HELP ME. THANKS

Comment: There are lots of controls that won't let you retrieve the text directly. As for `SysTreeView32` controls you can try the [low level SendMessage method](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/11115-get-text-of-treeview-control-item/).